# LIKE doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, mysql

I´working on a C# desktop App and want to search in a MYSQL database all the records that match with a specific name in order to display this records into a datagridview but got the error when executing the query with the value: pablo

[image]

this is my query

```
sentencia = "select * from registro where nombreParticipante LIKE '%' + @valor + '%'";
                    nombre = valor.ToUpper();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor", nombre);
                    cmd.CommandText = sentencia;
```

could you tell me what is wrong with the code please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format the string for your parameter rather than in the query:

```
sentencia = "select * from registro where nombreParticipante LIKE @valor";
                    nombre = valor.ToUpper();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor", "%" + nombre + "%");
                    cmd.CommandText = sentencia;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this code :

```
"select * from registro where nombreParticipante LIKE '% + @valor + %'";
```

The correct syntax of `LIKE` is :

```
WHERE 'STRING' LIKE '%OtherString%'
```

And what you did is:

```
WHERE 'STRING' LIKE '%'OtherString'%'
```